# buzzboost script on SharePoint page

Tags: javascript, rss

l am trying to display a buzz boost script from feed burner into a Content Editor web part but it is not working. I noticed that when I activate the web part it removes part of the JavaScript.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the script in a separate javascript file, store it in a document library or asset library, and add the link to the file in the Content Link box of the content editor web part.